# send super key to remote Citrix session

Tags: linux, citrix

I use Citrix Receiver on my home GNU/Linux Debian (testing) desktop to remote in to my work Windows machine.

I use Emacs extensively and I have many keybindings that use the super key or meta(alt)-shift combinations. However, neither my super keys (e.g. `s-g`) nor my meta-shift-letter combinations (e.g. `M-<`) are being passed through to the Windows machine. `s-g` seems to send `g` and `M-<` seems to send `<`.

1. How can I pass through all my shifted keystrokes?
2. How can I pass through the super modifier?

This is the closest thing I can find to documentation for the Citrix client settings, and I've not found anything of use: https://www.citrix.com/content/dam/citrix/en_us/documents/downloads/citrix-receiver/linux-oem-guide-13-0-bk.pdf

**UPDATE** by editing the `~/.ICAClient/All_Regions.ini` file to include

```
[Virtual Channels\Keyboard]
TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote
```

I can successfully nuke the super key on both local and remote. And `M-<` etc still don't get seen by the remote.

**UPDATE** http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX103576 introduces the `-keylog` command (which is obviously a major security hole, so ensure that you turn it off after using it) which allowed me to capture the keycodes that are being seen.

I realised that if I very slowly press `M` then `shift` then `.` (to achieve) `M-<` then Citrix is able to interpret it correctly and send the correct command to the remote emacs. This is less than ideal but at least it is a workaround. The keycodes that Citrix sees are

```
Key down: special 8/0x8
Key down: special 5/0x5
Key down: Unicode '<' - 60/0x3c
Key up: Unicode '<' - 60/0x3c
Key up: special 5/0x5
Key up: special 8/0x8
```

whereas a failed attempt looks like

```
Key down: special 5/0x5
Key down: special 64/0x40
Key down: Unicode '<' - 60/0x3c
Key up: Unicode '<' - 60/0x3c
Key up: special 64/0x40
Key up: special 5/0x5
```

The super key is being seen by citrix as `special 65/0x41` and if I do `s-f` it looks like this in the keylogger

```
Key down: special 65/0x41
Key down: Unicode 'f' - 102/0x66
Key up: Unicode 'f' - 102/0x66
Key up: special 65/0x41
```

but the Remote Emacs only sees the `f`.

**UPDATE** this is very weird. The remote can see `M-s-` (meta-super) bindings. It's just not able to see `s-` bindings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was on Debian 11, I added

```
[Virtual Channels\Keyboard]
TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote
```

except that, crucial change was to disable Wayland by going into /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf and uncommenting line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Only both of those two things worked for me.
Original knowledge came from [citrix forum](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/403094-alttab-will-not-work-on-citrix-workspace-for-linux-to-windows/)
.